# Get error message from Laravel validation

Tags: php, json, laravel

I use Laravel built-in validator and I want to get the first error message

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
     $error = $validator->messages()->toJson();
     .....
}
```

This is the result when I print error

```
{"name":["The name must be at least 5 characters."],"alamat":["The address must be at least 5 characters."]}
```

In the example above, I want to get the first error, which is "The name must be at least 5 characters.". How can I do that?

Answer (score 64):

Try this:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
   $error = $validator->errors()->first();
}
```

Answer (score 16):

As per 2019 Laravel 5.8 and above to get all the error messages from the validator is as easy as this:

```php
// create the validator and make a validation here...
if ($validator->fails()) {
    $fieldsWithErrorMessagesArray = $validator->messages()->get('*');
}
```

You will get the array of arrays of the fields' names and error messages. Something like this:

```
[
    'price'=>
        [ 
            0 => 'Price must be integer',
            1 => 'Price must be greater than 0'
        ]
    'password' => [
        [
            0 => 'Password is required'
        ]
    ]
    
]
```

You can use other validation messages getters that `Illuminate\Support\MessageBag` class provides (it is actually the object type that `$validator->messages()` above returns).

**Message Bag Error Messages Additional Helpers**

Go to `your_laravel_project_dir/vendor/illuminate/support/MessageBag.php` and find some useful methods like `keys`, `has`, `hasAny`, `first`, `all`, `isEmpty` etc. that you may need while checking for particular validation errors and customizing HTTP response messages.

It is easy to understand what they do by the look at the source code. Here is the [Laravel 6.x API reference](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.html) though probably less useful than the source code.

Answer (score 3):

If validation fails, the `withErrors` method can be used to flash the error messages to the session. This is an array and this method will automatically share `$errors` with all views after redirection.

```
return redirect('register')->withErrors($validator, 'login');
```

The `MessageBag` can be accessed using the instance from the `$errors` variable:

```
{{ $errors->login->first('email') }}
```

Form API [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#manually-creating-validators)

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In your ajax request, when you get the `data`, try `data.name`.

This will give you the error message for the `name` field.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/your-save-url",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData,
        success: function(data) { alert(data.name)}
    });
```

Comment: Not a solution of course. The data is not always in json format and the error field is not always name

Comment: `$error = $validator->messages()->toJson();` This statement indicates you are using `json` response. Also, the `json` field contains the name attribute of the field in your form. In your case, the names are `name` and `alamat`.

Comment: How to get the first error in the Laravel backend, so it returns "The name must be at least 5 characters."

Comment: `$error['name']` this will give the error for the `name`.

Answer (score 2):

for getting all errors, try this:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
   $error = $validator->errors()->all();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using toastr style error displaying, this will work:

```
@if(session()->get('errors'))
    toastr.error("{{ session()->get('errors')->first() }}");
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ($validator->fails())
{
    $error = $validator->messages()->get('name');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to do it inside the controller you can:

```
Arr::first(Arr::flatten($validator->messages()->get('*')))
```

you will get the first text message

```
The email must be accepted.
```