# how can i send laravel validation error messages in array in the blade file

Tags: laravel, validation, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-validation

i am working in the laravel, i am facing issue in passing laravel validation error messages to the blade template from the after function of the validator, i'm sending array of existing ids in the validation error message, i will use these ids in the blade template.

i have searched in the laravel documentation and also gone through other various websites but i haven't found the solution yet.

here is my model code

```
$validator = Validator::make($this->data, $this->rules(), $this->messages())->after(function ($validator) {
            if (isset($this->data['attribute_family'])) {
                $attribute_data = array();
                foreach ($this->data['attribute_family'] as$family) {
                    $family = Family::where('id',$family)->whereHas('attributes',function (Builder $query) {
                        $query->where('name',$this->data['name']);
                    })->first();
                    if ($family) {
                        $attribute_data[] = $family->id;
                    }
                }
                if (!empty($attribute_data)) {
                    $validator->errors()->add('duplicate_attribute_ids',$attribute_data);
                }
            }
        });
        return $validator;
```

and here is my blade template code in which i want to use laravel validation error message.

```
  <select name="attribute_family[]" id="" multiple="multiple" class="form-control sumoselect @error('attribute_family') is-invalid @enderror">
          @foreach($families as $family) 
       <option value="{{$family->id}}" class="@error('duplicate_attribute_ids') {{in_array($family->id, $message) ? 'is-invalid' : '' }} @enderror">{{$family->name}} </option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
```

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57555188/8352809) answer will be helpful for you

Comment: Are you throwing an error?  Just adding attributes into the error bag probably wont cause the request to be returned with errors.

Comment: @Snapey i am sending array in the error, which i will use to compare records in the blade file with family->id

Comment: You said. That does not mean that the framework will pass it to the view